# How to keep order element in JsonArray when put LinkHashMap

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring, sorting

I begin using JSON and i want keep element when put LinkHashMap to JsonArray. 
Here my code :

```
 JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();


        try {
            Map m = new LinkedHashMap(5);
            m.put("country", "VN");
            Map map = new LinkedHashMap(6);
            map.put("key","User");
            map.put("segmentation", m);
            ja.put(map);
            jo.put("events",ja);
```

When I put two key: **"key" and "segmentation"** it give me order. Now map order look like : **"key" : "User ","segmentation" : value** but when i using command **ja.put** it not order. It order: **"segmentation" : value ,"key" : "User "** . I want keep order **"key" : "User ","segmentation":value** in JSONArray but it not working. When i see method put it using HashMap not LinkHashMap and not keep my order. How to i keep my order in JsonArray look like : **"key" : "User ","segmentation" : value** in JsonArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different specification of a map called [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html). By default it will order the elements by natural ordering of the keys, but you can personalize the order by providing your own comparator.

Comment: When i using SortedMap. I using before put JsonArray or after put ? I think problem JsonArray not keep me order.